# communication with database through ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have following set of table rows which i have fetched from the database

```
    echo "<td value='".$id."' style='border:double' bgcolor='" . getcolour($catc) . "'  onclick = 'addValue(this.value);'>$id</td>";
```

this is actually a set of boxes and $id = $row['id'] is the number attached to each box. I want the mechanism like when a user clicks on the box the number attached to it should be echoed on a particular place on the webpage. MySql query and everything else works fine i have a problem with ajax code understanding i think so.

```
    <script>
    function valueAdd(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("seats").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
         document.getElementById("seats").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","ceckbus.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

waiting for ur help everyone!!

Comment: have you debugged your output to see what you are getting? Use the developer tools in google chrome to help you find out what the issue is.

Comment: you can use jquery get this will reduce your lines of code..

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest that you use a javascript library in order to use Ajax, and avoid trying to fix the compatibility issues at your own. For example you could use [jquery.com](http://jquery.com), it is pretty standard nowadays.

For the question part, please have a look at your echo code, there is an error at 'addValue(this.value);'

As I can understand the question, you want on the click event to have the $id. A simple fix it would be by using the innerHTML property, instead on .value:

```
 echo "<td value='".$id."' style='border:double' bgcolor='" . getcolour($catc) . "'  onclick = 'addValue(this.innerHTML);'>$id</td>";
```

or better on the echo you could pass the value directly to the addValue function, eg:

```
echo "<td value='".$id."' style='border:double' bgcolor='" . getcolour($catc) . "'  onclick = 'addValue(\"" . $id . "\");'>$id</td>";
```